# TexStudio on Linux suddenly not able to find installed packages

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

The following code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

all of a sudden gives the following error in TexStudio on Ubuntu 18.04 with TexLive:

> File `lipsum.sty' not found. \usepackage

BUT, I can successfully compile from bash:

`$ latex top.tex`

I'm thinking this might be because I removed LatexDraw using:

```
apt-get remove --purge latexdraw
apt-get autoremove
```

I've tried debugging this, so I list the outputs of some of the commands I ran:

- `which tex` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/tex`
- `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` gives `/home/me/texmf`, **a non-existing directory**
- `kpsewhich lipsum.sty` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty`
- Inside TexStudio, `Build/Commands ($PATH)` reads `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you start TeXStudio from a terminal (via `texstudio`)?

Comment: Just to elaborate on the comment by @PaulGaborit, if you're clicking an icon/launcher for TeXStudio then it will only have a few of it's environment variables set. However, when you open a terminal and launch it from there, typically more variables and paths are set. You should also consider upgrading to the latest distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my computer and it went back to working normally. 10 minutes later, the problem is back...

---

Before edit:

Once again, the solution is: restart your computer. Anyone who has a **real** solution or followup is welcome to post an answer.

Comment: Did you try just logging out and in again? Linux rarely need you to reboot. How exactly do you normally start texstudio.

Comment: @daleif Yes I did, unfortunately. Must just be this supergreat Ubuntu 18.04 that I got!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I see you have a local installation to a directory not in the default PATH. If you’re running TeX Studio from a launcher, this might therefore not be set.  You could try setting the command

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export PATH
```

to your system profile, `/etc/profile`, or a script in `/etc/profile.d`, rather than your user `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.  You also might want to set MANPATH and INFOPATH the same way.  And you should update the directory for your system, of course.

Comment: Don't set `MANPATH`. It is recommended to leave this empty. Then it is derived from `PATH`.

Comment: @cfr Maybe check it, and if and only if it's set, add the directory to the beginning.

Comment: Yes. If some distros set it, that would definitely be a better strategy. (Or if we don't know if it might get set, of course.)